# How to select data through different tables having one of them relationated with itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to consult all the Failures(Fallas) in the table `tblFalla` that belongs to an Area .

[image]

I relationate `tblArea` to itself in order to have 'n' Areas depending of 'n' Areas. I identify the main Areas of `tblArea` having the value `NULL` in the FK `idAreaPadre`.  So I can have the next data in `tblArea`:

[image]

The following Area path:

```
Ensamble -> Linea Principal
Ensamble -> Carriers -> GS1... -> Maquinado
Ensamble -> Carriers -> GS2...
And so on...
```

The data of `tblOperacion`:

[image]

How can I select all the Failures that belongs to a main area if the `tblArea` is relationated with itself? The user only says *"Hey give me all the failures ocurred in Assembly! [idArea 2]"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @idArea INT, @nomArea VARCHAR(50);
SET @idArea = 2;

SELECT @nomArea = nomArea
FROM #tblArea
WHERE idArea = @idArea;

WITH CTEAreas AS
(
    SELECT idArea, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),nomArea) nomArea, idAreaPadre
    FROM #tblArea
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  A.idArea, 
            CASE 
                WHEN A.idArea = @idArea THEN '' 
                ELSE @nomArea + ' -> '
            END + B.nomArea + ' -> ' + A.nomArea, 
            B.idAreaPadre
    FROM CTEAreas A
    INNER JOIN #tblArea B
        ON A.idAreaPadre = B.idArea
)
SELECT F.*, A.nomArea
FROM dbo.tblFalla F
INNER JOIN dbo.tblOperacion O
    ON F.idOperacion = O.idOperacion
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM CTEAreas
            WHERE idArea = @idArea OR idAreaPadre = @idArea) A
    ON O.idArea = A.IdArea
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 100); --you can change this to 0 if you 
                          --don't want to limit the recursions
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! But I have to show all the Area/Operacion path from where idOperacion comes too. Example: idOperacion = 6 in `tblFalla` the Area/Operacion path is **Ensamble->Carriers->GS2_INPUT->60**

Comment: Missed to declare @Area. From where am I supposed to get the path? I am not getting it in the results.

Comment: @KazMiller Updated my answer again

Comment: Just missed to add the name of the main Area when there is only one subArea after the main Area. When idOperacion = 1 it only tells me that is from Linea Principal instead Ensamble -> Linea Principal. Remember that there can be a lot of subAreas and Operations related at any Area level. Last update? You are awesome.